# Load Template-Part with Ajax in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Hi I am trying to add a feature to my store that when someone clicks on a product instead of being redirected to the product page, the product page loads with ajax in the home page like in this website (click on one of the products): http://www.itsjustyes.com. This is my jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){


$('.info_btn').on('click',function(){

    var theId = $(this).attr('id');


   var div = $('#product-container')
    $.post('wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',{
        action:'my_get_posts',post_id: theId
    }, function(data){
        console.log(data);
       div.html(data);
    })
    return false;
});
```

});

This is my code in functions.php:

```
//Ajax call to product
```

function my_get_posts_return()
{

```
global $post;


$post_id = intval(isset($_POST['post_id']) ? $_POST['post_id'] : 0);

if ($post_id > 0) {

    $the_query = new WP_query(array('p' => $post_id));
    if ($the_query->have_posts()) {
        while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();

            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );

        endwhile;
     } else {
        echo "There were no posts found";
    }
}


wp_die();
```

}

add_action('wp_ajax_my_get_posts', 'my_get_posts_return');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_get_posts', 'my_get_posts_return');

I keep getting that there were no posts found in the loop which is weird cause I know I am sending the right post id. By the way, if I try to get the individual parts of the product page with get_the_title( $post_id ) I get it just fine. It's only when I try to load the template part with the loop that I get this problem. Any idea what I am doing wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your WP_Query was not finding the correct post type.

```
$the_query = new WP_query(array('p' => $post_id));
```

The query above didn't return any post at all. By default, wordpress will assume that you're querying the post_type = 'posts' which is why you cannot find the product post.
Therefore, you need to specify what post_type you're looking for. With WooCommerce product, you can use:

```
$the_query = new WP_query(array('p' => $post_id, 'post_type' => 'product'));
```

P.S. It's a good practice to use wp_localize_script function to register your ajaxurl, rather than hard coded in your javascript. You can follow [this post](https://pippinsplugins.com/use-wp_localize_script-it-is-awesome/) for more detail.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That Worked! Thanks a lot. I knew I was close but was completely stuck. You totally saved me. Thanks.